# C: problem with operator '->', compile but return error. There are main.c and .h, .c files

Tags: c, list, initialization, structure, singly-linked-list

I'm new to the site. I use CodeBlocks. I am working with lists in C and I have to create a program with several functions but which has a header to declare them and another .c file to implement them, then call everything from main.c. The problem arises when I compile the code, insert n and then pressing enter as soon as it enters the for loop it goes into error. I believe there is a problem with the '->' operator. Could you help me please?

```c
    //main.c
    
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <list.h>
    
    int main()
    {
        struct element *list;
        list = create_list();
    
        return 0;
    }
```

```c
    //list.h
    
    #ifndef LIST_H_INCLUDED
    #define LIST_H_INCLUDED
    
    
    
    #endif // LIST_H_INCLUDED
    
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <malloc.h>
    
    struct element {
       int number;
       struct element *pointer;
    };
    
    struct element *create_list();
```

```c
    //list.c
    
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <malloc.h>
    #include <list.h>
    
    int n = 0;
    
    struct element *create_list() {
    
       struct element *p, *ptr;
       int i;
    
       printf("Insert the number of element of the list... ");
       scanf("%d", &n);
    
       if (n==0) {
    
        p = NULL;
    
       } else {
    
        p = (struct element*)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
        p->number = 0;
        for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    
            //printf("ciao\n");
            ptr->pointer = (struct element *)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
            ptr = ptr->pointer;
            ptr->number = i;
        }
    
        ptr->pointer = NULL;
       }
    
    return(p);
    }
```

Comment: Just a general comment: you should put code between header guards, not after them.

Comment: @Cb95 You are using uninitialized pointer ptr in this statement ptr->pointer = (struct element *)malloc(sizeof(struct element));

Comment: An inclusion guard should guard the whole file, not only first few lines. And you should check return value of `malloc`.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Isn't this initialization? struct element *p, *ptr;
Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Cb95 It is a declaration of variables with automatic storage duration, Such variable shall be explicitly initialized. Otherwise they have indeterminate values.

Comment: Can't believe this, but the moment I saw the question I knew it was uninitialized pointers cuz I ran into the same problem a while back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This declaration

```
struct element *p, *ptr;
```

declares two variables with automatic storage duration that have indeterminate values because they were not initialized explicitly.

So in this for loop

```
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {

        //printf("ciao\n");
        ptr->pointer = (struct element *)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
        ptr = ptr->pointer;
        ptr->number = i;
    }
```

you are using the uninitialized pointer `ptr` trying to access the data member `pointer` of a non-existent object.

It seems before the loop you mean the following assignment

```
    p = (struct element*)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
    p->number = 0;
    ptr = p;  // <===
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {

        //printf("ciao\n");
        ptr->pointer = (struct element *)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
        ptr = ptr->pointer;
        ptr->number = i;
    }
```

Pay attention to that it is a bad idea to declare the global variable n that moreover has a signed integer type instead of an unsigned integer type.

If the user will enter a negative number the function will return an unexpected result of a pointer to the node with the value equal to 0.

Also place declarations in the header between `#ifndef` and `#endif`

```
#ifndef LIST_H_INCLUDED
#define LIST_H_INCLUDED

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct element {
   int number;
   struct element *pointer;
};

struct element *create_list();    

#endif // LIST_H_INCLUDED
```

And the header `malloc.h` is not a standard C header. The memory allocation functions are in the header `<stdlib.h>`. Your program should work without the header `<malloc.h>`. So remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `ptr` with the following line:

```
struct element *p, *ptr;
```

But then, without allocating memory for it, you dereference the pointer ptr here:

```
ptr->pointer = (struct element *)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
```

This will of course, cause a segmentation fault.
You should first allocate memory for ptr before you can access its sub-elements.

Like this, for example:

```
ptr = (struct element*)malloc(sizeof(struct element));
```